# Berkeley integration bee 2021 finals problem

Tags: integration

Hi I would like to calculate this integral:

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(2x)\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\cos(2x)\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{2x^{3}-x} dx$

I tried reducing it to the following expression:

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin\left(2x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{2x^{3}-x} dx$

Now substitute $ u = \dfrac{1}{x} $ to get

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2}{x}-x\right)}{\dfrac{2}{x}-x} dx $

Now I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With some modifications, perhaps a complex-analytical approach might be viable, sort of like [in this similar integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326323/int-infty-infty-frac-sinx-frac-1xx-frac-1xdx-via-complex-analys?noredirect=1)?

Comment: I think [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) should be helpful for transforming it into more familiar integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin \left(2x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x \left(2 x^2-1\right)}\,dx$$

Let
$$2x-\frac{1}{x}=t\implies x=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{t^2+8}-t\right)\implies dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+8}}-1\right)\,dt$$ This makes
$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sin \left(2x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x \left(2 x^2-1\right)}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin (t)}{2 \sqrt{t^2+8}}\,dt+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin (t)}{2 t} \,dt$$

Over a symmetric interval, the first integral is $0$ and the second one is trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much!!